# What is the correct architecture design here?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, architecture

The problem is taken from initializing and retrieving data from Firebase, however I will translate this to pseudo in order those who are not familiar could also contribue.  Please consider the following code:
`

```
//Given the following API (from Firebase)
MyRemoteDBClass.asyncAuthenticate(initCompletedListener);
MyRemoteDBClass.asyncDataFetch(fetchCompletedListener)
// of course you have to authenticate before fetching the data
Class MyClassA.init()
{ 
    MyRemoteDBClass myRemoteDBClassInstance = new MyRemoteDBClass();
    myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncAuthenticate(some_listener);
}
// Then somewhere in the app:
Class MyClassB.asyncDataFetch(MyRemoteDBClass myRemoteDBClassInstance){
    myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncDataFetch(myClassBObject_as_listener) 
}`
```

The problem is that the calls of ClassA and ClassB are pretty close in timeline and I don't know if I get to call the asyncFetch before or after the init of myRemoteDBClassInstance was already completed.
How can I promise that I get to call myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncDataFetch method in MyClassB after the init was completed?

Comment: You can make the `init()` operation blocking, so it will wait for the authentication to complete. You need a `CountDownLatch` (initialized with a value of 1) shared between the listener and the `init()` method. In the listener you can do `latch.countDown()` and in the `init()` -  `latch.await()`

Answer (score 2):

Make your `some_listener` take a  `CompletableFuture`, and resolve it once the `asyncAuthenticate` is complete. It would end up looking something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
Listener some_listener = new Listener() {
   @override onAuthComplete() { future.complete(null); }
   //...
};

// Guts of your MyClassA.init
MyRemoteDBClass myRemoteDBClassInstance = new MyRemoteDBClass();
myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncAuthenticate(some_listener);

// ...

// Guts of your MyClassB.asyncDataFetch
future.get(); // Wait for auth to complete
myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncDataFetch(other_listener);
```

I like to use a future, since it allows us to return something more useful than a `Void` later, or to perform chaining of async calls nicely later.

Comment: in which case we should use approach suggested by me and in which cases the approach suggested by You?

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal It depends on desired behaviour. Michael's approach "waits" for the needed state to be reached, delaying the fetch but doing it in the end. Your approach just would end up not doing the fetch.

Comment: The approach of CompletableFuture is interesting. I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would initialize a state in MyClassA, to keep a record whether it is initialized. Then check this state in MyClassB.

```
Class MyClassA.init()
{ 
    MyRemoteDBClass myRemoteDBClassInstance = new MyRemoteDBClass();
    myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncAuthenticate(some_listener);
    static boolean initialized = true;//only sample code
}
static boolean MyClassA.isInitialized() {return initialized ;}

// Then somewhere in the app:
Class MyClassB.asyncDataFetch(MyRemoteDBClass myRemoteDBClassInstance){
  if (MyClassA.isInitialized()) { //only sample code
    myRemoteDBClassInstance.asyncDataFetch(myClassBObject_as_listener) 
 }
}
```

Comment: What if it's not initialized? Loop over and over until it is?

Comment: You want to be careful since your boolean is getting set from inside another thread. I'd at least use `AtomicBoolean` instead. And using a `static` variable is going to make unit testing your code a lot less fun - and introduces an unneeded binding between `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I just provide basic solution of checking if class is initialized. There is no clear visibility if `initialized` can be instance variable, since user has only posted very basic limited code.